# How to proper integrate PrismJS into a Eleventy project?

Tags: prismjs, eleventy

I'm building a site using [eleventy](https://11ty.dev) and want to include code examples with code-highlighting. [Prism](https://prismjs.com/) looks like a great choice for this. How would I add it proper to the build process (not as CDN)?

Comment: You could try [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org).  It has documentation for how to include in the build process with node.js

Answer (score 2):

Use the download option. This gives you the JS/CSS you need. Copy it to your site and ensure you are using the "Passthrough File Copy" (https://www.11ty.dev/docs/copy/) option to copy CSS and JS files over.